# How do I create an array of objects in json?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json object as shown.

```
this.model = {
            "cellType": "RemoveCell",
            "maxWidth": "800px",
            "items": {
                "columns" : [
                    {"attribute": "existingStrings", "title": "Existing Strings"},
                ],
                "rows" : [
                    {"existingStrings": this.stringList},
                ]
            }
        },
```

this.stringList is an array of strings (of varying size). How do declare this.stringList in the JSON object so that it behaves in this manner below?

```
this.model = {
            "cellType": "RemoveCell",
            "maxWidth": "800px",
            "items": {
                "columns" : [
                    {"attribute": "existingStrings", "title": "Existing Strings"},
                ],
                "rows" : [
                    {"existingStrings": this.stringList[0]},
                    {"existingStrings": this.stringList[1]},
                    {"existingStrings": this.stringList[2]},
                                      ...
                                      ...
                    {"existingStrings": this.stringList[n]},
                ]
            }
        },
```

I want "rows" to contain an array of objects (one object for each element in stringList). Thanks

Comment: do it with a for loop

Comment: But I can't iterate in a json object. This is fine if the size of the array is constant and known. In my case it is not. I can't hardcode it like this. Thanks

Comment: do a `foor loop` on `this.model.items.rows.existingStrings.length`, and build the array of objects you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var rows = [];

for ( var i=0; i<this.stringList.length; i++){
    rows.push({"existingStrings":this.stringList[i]});
}

this.model = {
        "cellType": "RemoveCell",
        "maxWidth": "800px",
        "items": {
            "columns" : [
                {"attribute": "existingStrings", "title": "Existing Strings"},
            ],
            "rows" : rows
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a function to build the list of objects

```
this.model = {
        "cellType": "RemoveCell",
        "maxWidth": "800px",
        "items": {
            "columns" : [
                {"attribute": "existingStrings", "title": "Existing Strings"},
            ],
            "rows" : 
                (function(){ 
                  var objList = []; 
                  for(var i = 0; i < this.stringList.length; i++)
                   objList.push({"existingStrings":this.stringList[i]});
                  return objList;
                })()
        }
    },
```

This works by using an IIFE (Immediately invoked function expression) as the value for "rows". `(function(){})` defines the function expression. When the `()` is used following the expression the function is invoked. Inside of the function is a for loop which builds an array of objects using `this.stringList`. Once the loop finishes, the array is returned, and that is the value which is assigned to "rows".

Comment: May be useful to precise to the reader that you will then have to call your array using `this.model.items.rows()` instead of `this.model.items.rows`.

Comment: @dgiugg - That is incorrect. The function is an immediately invoked function expression and evaluates to the array of objects.

Comment: This is a more elegant answer than mine. You've left out the `length` attribute in the for loop though - `this.stringList.length`.

Comment: I added a slight explanation of the process below, and also included `.length` (thanks for catching that).